# How do I get the absolute path of the chrome extensions directory?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm writing an app that has full access to the file system and I want to be able to get the absolute path of my extension's directory. How would I do this?

My app has permissions to `"<all_urls>", {"filesystem": [ "write" ]}` and has the "allow access to file urls" checked.

Comment: Just FYI, the `filesystem` permission only allows write access to [Chrome's sandboxed filesystem](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem.html), not the user's actual filesystem. From your permissions, I'd assume you want read access to the actual filesystem and read+write access to the sandboxed filesystem.

Comment: @apsillers No, I need read-write access to both. Is there another permission I need (on top of those and having the user check the "allow access to file URLs" checkbox)?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to Chrome extension API that allows write access to the actual file system (aside from letting the user save files as downloads). You can use an NPAPI plugin, but the learning curve is very steep and the tool is very powerful (and therefore dangerous, if you have a security vulnerability).

Comment: @apsillers If that's the case, then what does that check box do? Does it not apply?

Comment: @apsillers is right. If you do find a way to write to the extension folder without a user gesture it is a bug and you shouldn't rely on it. To be clear, the fileSystem permission is not for the sandboxed filesystem, which all apps can use. It is to get access to non-sandboxed files with user gestures. The checkbox is for XHR to file:// urls but you won't be able to get the path reliably, and it does not AFAIK enable write.

Comment: @DonRhummy I'd suggest asking another question explaining what your end goal is, if you haven't already. If we know what your app is trying to do at a higher level we might be able to propose something.

Comment: @BenWells By "user gestures" do you mean explicit file input, like `type="file"` inputs or drag-and-drop? I believe Chrome extension can do that by default -- the [permission page](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/declare_permissions.html) only says that the `fileSystem` permission is needed to access the [`chrome.fileSystem` API](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem.html) which says it can only access "a sandboxed section of the user's local file system." **However**, I've never used it, so I might be wrong!

Comment: @BenWells I want the app to be able to install other crx files (packed or unpacked) for development purposes. So if it can write into the extensions folder, it could do this (I believe). I also want the user to be able to say: "save files to this folder" and then the app would be able to write files and folders into there.

Comment: Maybe check out Text https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/text/mmfbcljfglbokpmkimbfghdkjmjhdgbg?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher It seems to maybe do somewhat of what you want.

Comment: @Duckbrain Unfortunately, that doesn't have any of the features I need. It can only open/save specific files you choose. It doesn't have the ability to create or read files in a folder you choose.

Comment: Is this something that you could write a native app for. I don't think you are going to be able to access those sorts of features in JavaScript for security reasons, like Ben Wells and Don Rhummy have said. Is this something that you only need for one operating system? I know that some Windows programs will inject their extensions into Chrome.

Comment: @Duckbrain I need ti for multiple Os's. It looks like I might have to use NPAPI for this.

Answer (score 11):

If you mean the file system path, that differs on each operating system. You can find it by doing a file search for your extensions identifier.

If you want a chrome reference, you can use:
`chrome.extension.getURL('');`
You can also provide something in the string and it will give you the path that you would need to reference the file contained in your app.

Example:

```
chrome.extension.getURL('index.html');
```

Returns:

```
"chrome-extension://gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp/index.html"
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I also need to list those as `web_accessible`?

Comment: I believe that is only if you are going to be using the resource in a content script (A script that is loaded into web sites outside of your app.) I may be wrong however.

Comment: chrome.extension doesn't exist on Chromium (linux), but the URL format is correct and works.

Comment: `chrome.extension` only exists in the context of a Chrome extension. i.e.: If you open the JavaScript console on an existing extension (even on Chromium).

Answer (score 2):

`chrome.extension.getURL` is deprecated now. use this instead:

```
chrome.runtime.getURL('index.html');
```